# Trio CS1352 oscilloscope trigger/blanking board photo needed

Tags: oscilloscope

It may be a very long shot. But is there any one with a Trio CS 1352 who could send me a photo of the trigger/blanking board both sides? My board has some weird jumpers that do not match the schematic and  I need to check and not sure if those are factory revision or previous owner fiddling around.

Comment: better chance is show jumpers on schematic with symptoms

Comment: At this moment one for sale at Marktplaats.nl for 45 euro